# C# windows mobile skins or fancy controls

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I am developing an application for a window mobile 6 using Visual Studio C# 2008 SP1.

However, the design of the application is very plain using the standard windows controls.

The application I am making is a phone that will be installed on WM6, so I am looking for controls that I can drag on to the form that resemble something that looks like a phone. Or just skins.

Any 3rd party controls or skins that can do this would be better? However, I don't mind paying for some if they fit for my application needs.

If there isn't any, any ideas how to make them myself? Any website tutorials?

Many thanks for any advice,

Steve

Comment: Are you looking for any specific controls, or do you just want to skin existing controls like buttons?

Comment: Hello. Well I think I would like to try both and see what is best. Can you point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I make a Ink component for Pocket PC check this at http://velocityink.codeplex.com/ if you interested.